# "Escritorio remoto no puede conectarse al equipo remoto" Máquina Virtual en Azure

Tags: azure, rdp, maquinas-virtuales

Tengo actualmente una Máquina Virtual con Windows 10 la cual había estado trabajando con normalidad, pero recientemente tuvo el problema de no permitir la conexión de archivo remoto.
Ya he restaurado una copia de seguridad antes de que empezara a fallar, pero el problema persiste.

1. Ya he habilitado el puerto RDP.
2. También he restablecido una copia de seguridad de cuando funcionaba todo, pero el problema sigue.

Aquí les dejo las reglas configuradas esperando puedan apoyarme.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las reglas del NSG parecen estar bien. Sigue esta guía de troubleshoting https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshoot-rdp-general-error?source=recommendations y si persiste la falla comparte capturas de pantalla de tus resultados